# Java Hibernate set parameter

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate

I was trying to use Hibernate to execute one simple query, However it gives error. I searched across web and parameter passing syntax seems correct, but no clue why is this happening.

**Code**

```
 Session session = analyticsSQLSession.getSession();

        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createNativeQuery("select * from :tableName");
            query.setParameter("tableName", tableName);

            List resultList = query.getResultList();
            session.close();
            System.out.println();

            return resultList;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            session.close();
```

**Error**

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"

Comment: You can't provide table name as a parameter.

Comment: @jarlh Seriously ? How can I achieve it if my tablename is going to change on every query ?

Comment: You build your query before hand, at least for the tablename.

Comment: This is not how you're supposed to use hibernate. nativeQuery are for side usage, and entityManager.findAll wil do that query for you. You need also to map all your table as classes. short story: either do your SQL with another framework, or take a hibernate tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here, you have to do something like this operation ,Try this one and let me know

```
 Session session = analyticsSQLSession.getSession();

        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query query =  session.createNativeQuery(tableName("tableName"));
            //query.setParameter("tableName", tableName);


            List resultList = query.getResultList();
            session.close();
            System.out.println();

            return resultList;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            session.close();



public static String tableName(String tableName) {
   return "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
}
```